# Rotate animation within translating element

Tags: angular, animation, rotation

I am building an Angular application with a collapsable menu. The button toggling the menu should rotate whenever the menu expands or collapses, so there is a rotating button on a resizing element (changing width/changing margin). The rotation works when there is no resizing, but as soon as the parent element is being resized, the rotation animation is not shown. This here is a minimal example showing my problem:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, trigger, state, transition, style } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
  animations: [
    trigger('translate', [
      state('moveRight', style({ marginLeft: '200px' })),
      state('moveLeft', style({ marginLeft: '0px' })),
      transition('moveRight => moveLeft', [ animate('0.5s') ]),
      transition('moveLeft => moveRight', [ animate('0.5s') ])      
    ]),    
    trigger('rotate', [
      state('turnRight', style({ transform: 'rotate(0deg)' })),
      state('turnLeft', style({ transform: 'rotate(180deg)' })),
      transition('turnRight => turnLeft', [ animate('0.5s') ]),
      transition('turnLeft => turnRight', [ animate('0.5s') ])      
    ])
  ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
  isToggled = true;

  toggle() {
    this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
  }
}
```

And this is my template:

```
<div [@translate]="isToggled ? 'moveRight' : 'moveLeft'">
    <div [@rotate]="isToggled ? 'turnRight' : 'turnLeft'" (click)="toggle()" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</div>
```

When I remove the `@translate`-animation from the outer div, the rotate animation is performed, otherwise I only see the moving animation. Happens both in Chrome and Firefox, I am running Angular 8.

Comment: Not that you asked for this, but you can simplify the transition code: `transition('turnLeft <=> turnRight', [ animate('0.5s') ])`. The `<=>` will enable the transition both ways.

Comment: There must be somethig else. Your code works perfectly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxklx8

Comment: @Danilo No, his problem is that rotate action is not an animation but run only at the end (without animate).

Comment: Thanks, but when I open the stackblitz, I see the translate-animation (Hello World moving to the left), then the Hello World flips upside down, but there is no rotate-animation. I'd expect a rotate-animation.

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be to combine the two animations.

```
    trigger('translate', [
      /*
      state('moveRight', style({ transform: 'translateX(200px)' })),
      state('moveLeft', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
      transition('moveRight => moveLeft', [ animate('0.5s') ]),
      transition('moveLeft => moveRight', [ animate('0.5s') ]),
       */
    ]),    
    trigger('rotate', [
      state('turnRight', style({ transform: 'rotate(0deg) translateX(200px)' })),
      state('turnLeft', style({ transform: 'rotate(180deg) translateX(0)' })),
      transition('turnRight => turnLeft', [ animate('0.5s') ]),
      transition('turnLeft => turnRight', [ animate('0.5s') ])
    ])
  ]
```

Here a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-translate-rotate-animation?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but that doesn't really help: The outer div does not move, but it should. The inner div should rotate within the outer div moving.
I found a solution now: I define the rotation in my stylesheet using plain SASS/CSS and trigger it by adding/removing classes associated with the animation.